# Extracting raster value to specific range using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, spatial-analyst

I have multiple rasters with range 0 - 255. I want to extract range from 0 to 100 using Arc GIS python script and after extraction I want to multiply all raster by 0.01 and save it with same name as it input using loop function. I have made one script till raster extraction, but I am getting an error while running the script. Below I have shown my script.

```
import arcpy, os      
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')      
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\MODIS-NDVI\FPAR-2005\MASKED-FPAR-05"      
outFolder = r"D:\MODIS-NDVI\FPAR-2005\MASKED-FPAR-05A"    
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")    
list = arcpy.ListRasters     
for inRaster in rasters:    
    outRaster = outFolder + "\\" + inRaster 
    arcpy.sa.con(inRaster >3000,inRaster)
```

Comment: welcom to GIS SE. Please add the error message when you post this kind of question. Why is it in your script > 3000 and your text between 0 and 100 ?

Answer (score 2):

there are a few things to check, but your error could be a missing indentation, "con" without a capital letter or the missing () after ListRasters. I've replaced some part of your code (not all changes are necessary) and added the save.

```
import arcpy, os  
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')  

arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\MODIS-NDVI\FPAR-2005\MASKED-FPAR-05"  

outFolder = r"D:\MODIS-NDVI\FPAR-2005\MASKED-FPAR-05A"

list = arcpy.ListRasters() 

for inRaster in list:
    localRaster = Raster(inRaster)
    outRaster = Con(localRaster >3000, localRaster*0.01)
    outRaster.save(outFolder + "\\" + inRaster )
```